# Recursive listing of Files in SharePoint Library

Tags: list, document-library, file

I got lost after 2 days of development and searching in here. I need to list recursively files in SP library with subfolders. 
Current structure is:

- Testing Folder (1 file)

  - Subfolder1 (1file)
  - Subfolder2 (1 file)

I am using scope of the view set up to recursive all, but I am getting only 1 file from the Testing Folder, not from the subfolders.

What I did:

```
     SP.ClientContext context = new SP.ClientContext(endpoint);
     context.Credentials = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, securedPassword);
     SP.Web web = context.Web;
     context.Load(web);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     relativeFolder = "/our/team/MainStorage/TestingFolder/";
     SP.Folder listFolder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(relativeFolder);
     var listStorage = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Main Team Storage");
     context.Load(listStorage);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     SP.CamlQuery queryFolder = new SP.CamlQuery();
     queryFolder.ViewXml = @"<QueryOptions>
      <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
      <Folder>'MainStorage/TestingFolder'</Folder>
  <Query>
      <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq></Where>
  </Query></QueryOptions>";
     var listItemsQ = listStorage.GetItems(queryFolder);
     context.Load(listItemsQ);
     context.ExecuteQuery();
     foreach (var item in listItemsQ)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("item is " + item);
        }
```

I am still getting only one file, can anyone help please? Thank you so much.